# meaning of 'deed of love'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Does 'deed of love' mean *deed caused by love* or it mean something else?

Example:

> Life and hope for the world are to be found only in the **deeds of love**.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, yes, it means deeds that are motivated by love, or that show love.

Careful, though. It could have a much more *physical* connotation in some contexts. The more usual term for that, being poetic in this way, would be *acts of love*, but I've come across *deeds* used for the same thing.